# Пересечение двух прямоугольных треугольников

Tags: c++

Как проверить пересечение двух прямоугольных треугольников? по координатам.

Comment: хм.. фигура это какая то площадь, массив. две фигуры два массива, берешь два массива и ищещь внутри них одинаковые точки к примеру 1:1 - вот тут пересечение

Comment: О каком именно "пересечении" идет речь? Пересечение треугольных областей? Или пересечение границ треугольных областей? Если один треугольник лежит целиком внутри другого - это пересечение или нет?

Comment: При чём здесь c++? Это задача по геометрии.

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? Приведите пример, как именно вы треугольник в массив запихнёте, чтобы по этому массиву можно было пересечение искать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код для произвольных треугольников. Писал на коленке, но вроде бы все работает.

Домашнее задание:

1. Выяснить, можно ли как-то оптимизировать алгоритм, зная, что треугольники прямоугольные.
2. Избавиться от многократного вычисления `GetWinding` для одних и тех же троек точек.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Point {float x, y;};
struct Triangle {Point points[3];};

// Знак возвращаемого значения показывает, с какой стороны (слева или справа)
// точка C находится от вектора AB.
float GetWinding(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
    // Находятся вектора AB и AC. Дополняются до трехмерных добавлением Z = 0.
    // Вычисляется их векторное произведение, от которого берется только
    // Z-координата.
    float x1 = b.x - a.x, y1 = b.y - a.y;
    float x2 = c.x - a.x, y2 = c.y - a.y;
    return x1 * y2 - x2 * y1;
}

// Изменяет треугольник ABC так, чтобы GetWinding(A,B,C) было >= 0.
// Если это условие уже выполняется, треугольник возвращается без изменений.
// Иначе точки B и C меняются местами.
Triangle FixWinding(Triangle tri)
{
    if (GetWinding(tri.points[0], tri.points[1], tri.points[2]) < 0)
        std::swap(tri.points[1], tri.points[2]);
    return tri;
}

// Проверяет, находится ли точка внутри треугольника.
// Предполагается, что к треугольнику уже была применена FixWinding().
bool PointTriangleCollision(Point p, Triangle tri)
{
    return GetWinding(tri.points[0], tri.points[1], p) >= 0 &&
           GetWinding(tri.points[1], tri.points[2], p) >= 0 &&
           GetWinding(tri.points[2], tri.points[0], p) >= 0;
}

// Проверяет два отрезка A и B на пересечение.
bool EdgeEdgeCollision(Point a1, Point a2, Point b1, Point b2)
{
    return GetWinding(a1, a2, b1) * GetWinding(a1, a2, b2) <= 0 &&
           GetWinding(b1, b2, a1) * GetWinding(b1, b2, a2) <= 0;
}

// Проверяет два треугольника на пересечение.
// Предполагается, что к треугольникам уже была применена FixWinding().
bool TriangleTriangleCollision(Triangle a, Triangle b)
{
    // Если хотя бы один угол одного треугольника внутри
    // другого треугольника, то пересечение есть.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (PointTriangleCollision(a.points[i], b))
            return 1;
        if (PointTriangleCollision(b.points[i], a))
            return 1;
    }

    // Если хотя бы одна пара ребер разных треугольников
    // пересекается, то треугольники пересекаются.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        int i_next = (i + 1) % 3;
        int j_next = (j + 1) % 3;
        if (EdgeEdgeCollision(a.points[i], a.points[i_next], b.points[j], b.points[j_next]))
            return 1;
    }

    // Иначе - нет пересечения.
    return 0;
}

// Делает то же, что TriangleTriangleCollision(), но сама
// применяет FixWinding к аргументам.
bool TriangleTriangleTest(Triangle a, Triangle b)
{
    return TriangleTriangleCollision(FixWinding(a), FixWinding(b));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << TriangleTriangleTest({{{1,1},{3,1},{1,3}}}, {{{11,11},{11,10},{10,11}}}) << '\n';
    std::cout << TriangleTriangleTest({{{1,1},{3,1},{1,3}}}, {{{1.5,1.5},{10,9},{9,10}}}) << '\n';
    std::cout << TriangleTriangleTest({{{1,1},{3,1},{1,3}}}, {{{2,2},{2,2.1},{2.1,2}}}) << '\n';
    std::cout << TriangleTriangleTest({{{-3,2},{3,2},{0,-4}}}, {{{3,-2},{-3,-2},{0,4}}}) << '\n';
}
```

---

> О каком именно "пересечении" идет речь? Пересечение треугольных областей? Или пересечение границ треугольных областей? Если один треугольник лежит целиком внутри другого - это пересечение или нет?

Я предположил, что ситуация, когда один треугольник целиком внутри другого, считается за пересечение. Если это не так, то нужно убрать первую половину `TriangleTriangleCollision()` и все связанные функции.

Comment: Если уж писать комментарии, то стоит отметить ключевой момент: функция  `LineLineCollision` детектирует именно пересечение *отрезков*, а не пересечение *прямых*. Название `LineLineCollision` сбивает с толку, ибо "line" - это "прямая".

Comment: @AnT Согласен, поправил комментарий и заменил line на edge.

Answer (score 0):

Метод разделяющих осей ([Separating axis theorem](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/), [ещё](http://mr-kody.blogspot.com/2010/10/2d-separate-axis-theorem.html))  работает для любых выпуклых многоугольников, в т.ч. и для треугольников

Вероятно, он будет близок по эффективности прямому методу, проверяющему пересечение каждой стороны одного треугольника с двумя сторонами другого (на основе знаков векторного произведения) + тест на полное вхождение.

Возможно в конкретной задаче есть дополнительные условия, которые позволят организовать более простую проверку (хотя метод SAT несложен)

Answer (score 0):

Каким образом можно воспользоваться прямоугольностью треугольников - не знаю. Подозреваю, что на уровне общей задачи этим воспользоваться нельзя и придется решать задачу для произвольных треугольников. (На уровне внутренних вычислений, возможно, что-то получится оптимизировать.)

Если речь идет об обнаружении пересечения треугольных *областей* `A` и `B`, то такое пересечение существует, если границы областей пересекаются или одна область лежит внутри другой. Это дает нам следующий (достаточно лобовой алгоритм проверки)

1. Каждую сторону треугольника `A` проверяем на пересечение с каждой стороной треугольника `B`. Для этого надо будет девять раз (*максимум* девять раз) проверить наличие пересечения двух *отрезков*. Если пересечение обнаружено, то треугольники пересекаются.
2. В противном случае берем некую внутреннюю точку треугольника `A` и проверяем, не лежит ли она внутри треугольника `B`. И наоборот: берем некую внутреннюю точку треугольника `B` и проверяем, не лежит ли она внутри треугольника `A`. Если одна из этих двух проверок обнаружит точку, лежащую внутри, то треугольники пересекаются.

Как обычно в таких случаях, надо принять решение о том, как расценивать пограничные ситуации, т.е. касание треугольников.